# Parse error on input ‘module’ when importing a module

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

This is the source code of the file Solitaire.hs:

```
import MergeSort

module Solitaire where

  a :: Int

  a = 2
```

MergeSort.hs and Solitaire.hs are in the same directory.

I'm using WinGhci.

The error I'm getting when trying to load Solitaire.hs after changing to its directory and using the command :load Solitaire.hs is:

```
Solitaire.hs:3:1: error: parse error on input ‘module’
  |
3 | module Solitaire where   | ^^^^^^
Failed, one module loaded.
*MergeSort>
```

What's curious is, that just removing the import statement: `import MergeSort` removes any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [grammar](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html) (5.1):

```
module  →   module modid [exports] where body
       |    body
body    →   { impdecls ; topdecls }
       |    { impdecls }
       |    { topdecls }

impdecls    →   impdecl1 ; … ; impdecln     (n ≥ 1)
topdecls    →   topdecl1 ; … ; topdecln     (n ≥ 1)
```

Also, in Section 5.3:

> The entities exported by a module may be brought into scope in another module with an import declaration *at the beginning of the module*.

As you can see, imports must be *inside* the module, so your code should be:

```
module Solitaire where
    import MergeSort

    a :: Int
    a = 2
```

Comment: Oh, that worked. I was almost certain I tried that. I must've tried it without indenting it properly or something. Thank you for the very much for the detailed response.

Comment: @AndreiTihoan, it's completely *optional* to indent module contents like that, and in my experience it's *rare*. The vast majority of Haskell programmers start their imports and top-level definitions in column 0 so they can make the best use of limited horizontal space. But whatever column you start the module contents in is the one you have to put the rest in.

Comment: Thanks again @ForceBru. It does actually look better when not indented. Also, thank you for cleaning up my question. It was my first post, and I made it in a bit of a hurry, not realizing my code wasn't properly written under code.

Comment: @AndreiTihoan, you should thank defer for the idea about indentation, not me :D As for question formatting, you can find more information about how and what to post in the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to Stack Overflow!